# Retrieve latest Commit links and message with GitHub Api and Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, github-api

I have reproduced my case with this jsbin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xeninaceze/edit?js,output

Github API allows me to get the list of events by author:

**API Link - api.github.com/users/:user/events**

I can access to the commit message filtering the events “PushEvent”, and it s perfectly fine because i cam stream my latest commit message.

```
var gitactivitiesPromise = function() {
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function (resolve) {
    Ember.$.ajax(eventsAct, {
      success: function(events) {
        var result = [];
        events.filter(function(event) {
          return event.type == 'PushEvent';
        }).forEach(function(item){
          item.payload.commits.map(function(commit){
            result.push(store.createRecord('commit', {
              message: commit.message,
            }));
          });


        });
        resolve(result);
      },  
      error: function(reason) {
        reject(reason);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

The problem is that i want to stream beside the **msg** also his **own url link**. `html_url`

I need to know **how i can tackle it**? since the commit url links are not in the in the API Link

- api.github.com/users/:user/events

But they are in the following api

- api.github.com/repos/:user/repo/commits/branch

This makes bit more complicate to access to the latest commits url link `html_url`

This is a good example of what i am trying to do

http://zmoazeni.github.io/gitspective/#

It streams in the push events the latest **commits message** with **links**

Comment: Have you looked at the code base at https://github.com/zmoazeni/gitspective ? Is there something specific you cannot follow about using the APIs that is demonstrated there?

Comment: i can not set it up to debug https://github.com/zmoazeni/gitspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that all the relevant data is already there:

```
{
    "id": "3414229549",
    "type": "PushEvent",
    "actor": {
      ...
      "login": "paulirish"
    },
    "repo": {
      ...
      "name": "GoogleChrome/devtools-docs"
    },
    "payload": {
      ...
      "commits": [
        {
          ...
          "message": "fish shell. really liking it.",
          "sha": "1f9740c9dd07f166cb4b92ad053b17dbc014145b"
        },
    ...
```

You can access the author URL as `actor` and the repository as `repo`. With this it's easy to construct the relevant links:

```
...
.forEach(function(item) {
  var repoUrl = 'https://github.com/' + item.repo.name;
  var authorUrl = 'https://github.com/' + item.actor.login;

  item.payload.commits.map(function(commit) {
    result.push(store.createRecord('commit', {
      authorUrl: authorUrl,
      repositoryUrl: repoUrl,
      commitUrl: repoUrl + '/commit/' + commit.sha,
      message: commit.message
    }));
  });
})
...
```

Updated JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/feyedujulu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: This is the problem. i do not need the commit.url which is 

https://api.github.com/repos/paulirish/dotfiles/commits/1f9740c9dd07f166cb4b92ad053b17dbc014145b

But I need his own html_url which is there, if you click on it
https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles/commit/1f9740c9dd07f166cb4b92ad053b17dbc014145b

Comment: Ah, so you need the actual URL for the user, not the API endpoint! Give me a bit to adjust my answer.

Comment: would you mind to update my jsbin to accept the answer?

Comment: I found two details: A missing `/` in the author URL and I wrote `commits` instead of `commit` for the URL :-) Both are corrected now, the updated JSBin is in the answer.